# Sampling Points and Areas around them

Tags: qgis, nearest-neighbor, sampling

I have some coordinates in QGIS. I want to sample the values corresponding to those coordinates on a layer. I know that I can do that for the exact point using 'Point Sampling Tool'. Is there also a way to not only sample the exact point but an area of about 9 point around the coordinate using the nearest neighbor method?

Comment: Just to clarify, what do you mean "an area of about 9 point around the coordinate"? Do you mean using 9 existing points and performing an average of the sampled values for each or are you actually interested in an area around the point (i.e. a buffer)?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: @Georgeofalltrades your first suggestion. I would like to do kind of an Nearest Neighbor interpolation of a 9 raster square with my coordinate being in the middle. The new value should then somehow be assigned to my coordinate to do a point sampling.